# Is it good to use the latest version of OpenSSL with Indy or not?

Tags: delphi, openssl, indy

I just upgraded Indy to th latest version (10.5.7), I was using the OpenSSL dlls in version 0.9.8.13.

Is it good to use the latest version (1.0.0a) or since the version I have (0.9.8.13) works fine it is a risk to upgrade since there can be bugs in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are ready, read here [OpenSSL v0.9.8o and v1.0.0a for Indy](http://blog.digivendo.com/2010/06/openssl-v0-9-8o-and-v1-0-0a-for-indy/)

but read this note on the blog

> Note: This version needs the very
>   latest Indy SVN (Revision #4168 and
>   newer). This is due to changes in
>   OpenSSL (i.e. removing deprecated MD2
>   by default).

Comment: Sorry SVN rev 4168 stands for 10.5.7?

Comment: rev 4168 in Indy's SVN server, Tiburon branch (not the Trunk).